# Birkat kohanim at shacharit and ne'ilah of Yom Kippur

Tags: minhag, yom-kippur, ashkenazi, birchas-kohanim, neilah

[Rema Orach Chayyim 128:44](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128.44?lang=bi) notes that some Ashkenazi communities recite *birkat kohanim* at *ne'ilah* of Yom Kippur, and some even at *shacharit*.

Every Ashkenazi synagogue (outside of Israel) that I've attended on Yom Kippur has only recited *birkat kohanim* at *musaf*.

**Are there any extant Ashkenazi communities in *chutz la'aretz* that still recite *birkat kohanim* at *shacharit* or *ne'ilah* of Yom Kippur?**

Comment: I visited a Chabad (I believe) in Vancouver, Canada, that duchaned at ne'ilah. I don't know if that was a one-off or if they do that regularly.